# Pinging/Connecting windows PC in the same network from a Linux PC in the same network

Tags: android, linux, windows, networking, lan

I have Ubuntu 12.04 Linux machine and I have created a local network from the Windows machine (Windows Server 2008 installed on it) .With this network I can connect among the windows machines but I am not able to enter into this network from a Linux machine.More over I have an android device which is also connected in this network ( shows in the settings) but I am not able to ping it as well from the Linux machine.
Is there any network discovery machine option in Linux which I have to enable.

On Pinging another Ip Address I get this :

```
From <ip address> icmp_seq = 1 Destination Net Unreachable .
```

There is no proxy settings.

Comment: what is the network address used by Windows network and that of the linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give static IP addresses to each device on their subnet mask.

And then ping each other.